# It doesn't redirect me to the controller's index

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am very new to asp.net mvc and I am trying to implement users with their roles, at the time of giving the navbar options if I enter as "admin" these send me back to the login even though I am registered.
What I want is to send me to the Index of those controllers.
This is the controller that handles the login and logout:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly IUserHelper _userHelper;

    public AccountController(IUserHelper userHelper)
    {
        _userHelper = userHelper;
    }
    public IActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public  async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var result = await _userHelper.LoginAsync(model);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                if (Request.Query.Keys.Contains("ReturnUrl"))
                {
                    return Redirect(Request.Query["ReturnUrl"].First());
                }
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"); 
            }
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Usuario o contraseña erroneo! ");
            
        }
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
    {
        await _userHelper.LogoutAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
}
```

For example this is one of the controllers that I want only the "Admin" to access:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public class AgendaController : Controller
{
    private readonly DataContext _context;

    public AgendaController(DataContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: Agenda
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        return View(await _context.Agendas.ToListAsync());
    }

    // GET: Agenda/Details/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var agenda = await _context.Agendas
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
        if (agenda == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(agenda);
    }

    // GET: Agenda/Create
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Agenda/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to.
    // For more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Date,Remarks,IsAvailable")] Agenda agenda)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(agenda);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(agenda);
    }

    // GET: Agenda/Edit/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var agenda = await _context.Agendas.FindAsync(id);
        if (agenda == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return View(agenda);
    }

    // POST: Agenda/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to.
    // For more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("Id,Date,Remarks,IsAvailable")] Agenda agenda)
    {
        if (id != agenda.Id)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                _context.Update(agenda);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!AgendaExists(agenda.Id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(agenda);
    }

    // GET: Agenda/Delete/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var agenda = await _context.Agendas
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
        if (agenda == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(agenda);
    }

    // POST: Agenda/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        var agenda = await _context.Agendas.FindAsync(id);
        _context.Agendas.Remove(agenda);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

    private bool AgendaExists(int id)
    {
        return _context.Agendas.Any(e => e.Id == id);
    }
}
```

I made use of helpers for these actions:

```
public class UserHelper : IUserHelper
{
    private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;
    private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<User> _signInManager;

    public UserHelper(
        UserManager<User> userManager,
        RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager,
        SignInManager<User> signInManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _roleManager = roleManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
    }

    public async Task<SignInResult> LoginAsync(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        return await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(
           model.Username,
           model.Password,
           model.RememberMe,
           false);
    }

    public async Task LogoutAsync()
    {
        await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
    }


    public async Task<IdentityResult> AddUserAsync(User user, string password)
    {
        return await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, password);
    }

    public async Task AddUserToRoleAsync(User user, string roleName)
    {
        await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, roleName);
    }

    public async Task CheckRoleAsync(string roleName)
    {
        var roleExists = await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(roleName);
        if (!roleExists)
        {
            await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole
            {
                Name = roleName
            });
        }
    }

    public async Task<User> GetUserByEmailAsync(string email)
    {
        return await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);
    }

    public async Task<bool> IsUserInRoleAsync(User user, string roleName)
    {
        return await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, roleName);
    }
}
```

Interface:

```
public interface IUserHelper
{
    Task<User> GetUserByEmailAsync(string email);

    Task<IdentityResult> AddUserAsync(User user, string password);

    Task CheckRoleAsync(string roleName);

    Task AddUserToRoleAsync(User user, string roleName);

    Task<bool> IsUserInRoleAsync(User user, string roleName);

    Task<SignInResult> LoginAsync(LoginViewModel model);

    Task LogoutAsync();
}
```

Create a feed for the database and enter some records:

```
public class SeedDb
{
    private readonly DataContext _dataContext;
    private readonly IUserHelper _userHelper;

    public SeedDb(
        DataContext context,
        IUserHelper userHelper)
    {
        _dataContext = context;
        _userHelper = userHelper;
    }

    public async Task SeedAsync()
    {
        await _dataContext.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync();
        await CheckRoles();
        var manager = await CheckUserAsync("00148989898", "Juan", "Corderp", "jzuluaga55@gmail.com", "809 634 2747", "Admin");
        var customer = await CheckUserAsync("40217655544", "Julieta", "Maria", "jmaria@hotmail.com", "829 634 2747", "Customer");
        await CheckPetTypesAsync();
        await CheckServiceTypesAsync();
        await CheckOwnerAsync(customer);
        await CheckManagerAsync(manager);
        await CheckPetsAsync();
        await CheckAgendasAsync();
    }

    private async Task CheckRoles()
    {
        await _userHelper.CheckRoleAsync("Admin");
        await _userHelper.CheckRoleAsync("Customer");
    }

    private async Task<User> CheckUserAsync(string document, string firstName, string lastName, string email, string phone,  string role)
    {
        var user = await _userHelper.GetUserByEmailAsync(email);
        if (user == null)
        {
            user = new User
            {
                FirstName = firstName,
                LastName = lastName,
                Email = email,
                UserName = email,
                PhoneNumber = phone,
                Document = document
                
                
            };

            await _userHelper.AddUserAsync(user, "123456");
            await _userHelper.AddUserToRoleAsync(user, role);
        }

        return user;
    }

    private async Task CheckPetsAsync()
    {
        if (!_dataContext.Pets.Any())
        {
            var owner = _dataContext.Owners.FirstOrDefault();
            var petType = _dataContext.PetTypes.FirstOrDefault();
            AddPet("Otto", owner, petType, "Shih tzu");
            AddPet("Killer", owner, petType, "Dobermann");
            await _dataContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }

    private async Task CheckServiceTypesAsync()
    {
        if (!_dataContext.ServiceTypes.Any())
        {
            _dataContext.ServiceTypes.Add(new ServiceType { Name = "Consulta" });
            _dataContext.ServiceTypes.Add(new ServiceType { Name = "Urgencia" });
            _dataContext.ServiceTypes.Add(new ServiceType { Name = "Vacunación" });
            await _dataContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }

    private async Task CheckPetTypesAsync()
    {
        if (!_dataContext.PetTypes.Any())
        {
            _dataContext.PetTypes.Add(new PetType { Name = "Perro" });
            _dataContext.PetTypes.Add(new PetType { Name = "Gato" });
            await _dataContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }

    private async Task CheckOwnerAsync(User user)
    {
        if (!_dataContext.Owners.Any())
        {
            _dataContext.Owners.Add(new Owner { User = user });
            await _dataContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }

    private async Task CheckManagerAsync(User user)
    {
        if (!_dataContext.Managers.Any())
        {
            _dataContext.Managers.Add(new Manager { User = user });
            await _dataContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }

    private void AddPet(string name, Owner owner, PetType petType, string race)
    {
        _dataContext.Pets.Add(new Pet
        {
            Born = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2),
            Name = name,
            Owner = owner,
            PetType = petType,
            Race = race
        });
    }

    private async Task CheckAgendasAsync()
    {
        if (!_dataContext.Agendas.Any())
        {
            var initialDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 8, 0, 0);
            var finalDate = initialDate.AddYears(1);
            while (initialDate < finalDate)
            {
                if (initialDate.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
                {
                    var finalDate2 = initialDate.AddHours(10);
                    while (initialDate < finalDate2)
                    {
                        _dataContext.Agendas.Add(new Agenda
                        {
                            Date = initialDate,
                            IsAvailable = true
                        });

                        initialDate = initialDate.AddMinutes(30);
                    }

                    initialDate = initialDate.AddHours(14);
                }
                else
                {
                    initialDate = initialDate.AddDays(1);
                }
            }
        }

        await _dataContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

And in this way I am managing that it is seen in the Home if you enter as "Admin":

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
        </li>

        @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && User.IsInRole("Admin"))
        {
                            
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Owners" asp-action="Index">Clientes</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Managers" asp-action="Index">Administradores</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Agenda" asp-action="Index">Agenda</a>
        </li>
        }
                    
    </ul>
</div>
```

I know it's a lot and I appreciate any help and hopefully I can solve this.

The startup class:

```
   public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
            cfg.Password.RequireDigit = false;
            cfg.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 0;
            cfg.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            cfg.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            cfg.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
        }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataContext>();

        services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(cfg => cfg.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConectionstring")));
        services.AddTransient<SeedDb>();
        services.AddScoped<IUserHelper, UserHelper>();
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

}

Comment: When checking your database, are there any entries in AspNetUserRoles? If not try normalizing your roles when seeding your database `"Admin".ToUpper()`

Comment: Does it work if you remove the Authorize attribute? Where "work" means that it does not readirect to login? If yes, does it work if you add the Athorize attribute again but without the roles requirement?

Comment: Yes, removing the Authorize works

Comment: Hi @KevenCorrea,can you share your startup class?